# Set Super Column Family in Cassandra Cli

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface, super-columns

I'm using Cassandra 0.8.0.

I cannot figure out how to use the Cassandra-Cli to add values to a currently existing SuperColumn. For example: I have added the following to my keyspace

```
create column family authors
with comparator = UTF8Type and subcomparator = UTF8Type
and default_validation_class = UTF8Type
and column_metadata = [{
    column_name: tags, validation_class: UTF8Type},
    {column_name: url, validation_class:UTF8Type},
    {column_name: title, validation_class: UTF8Type},
    {column_name: publisher, validation_class: UTF8Type},
    {column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}];
```

I tried adding a row to this super column doing:
(input)`[default@testspace] set authors[1]['1']['url'] = 'www.henry.com';`

(output) `[default@testspace] null` 
which is an error^

I try this too:

```
[default@testspace] set authors['henry']['url']['1'] = 'www.henry.com';
```

and get:

```
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: cannot parse 'henry' as hex bytes
```

what is the proper syntax for manipulating SuperColumns in the Cassandra-Cli? Can you provide an example to set/get values using a supercolumn in cassandra-cli?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add

```
column_type = 'Super' and key_validation_class = UTF8Type
```

to your column family definition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you if Cassandra will support indexing subcolumns in super columns?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create secondary indexes on the sub-columns of a super column. Therefore, the use of super columns is best suited for use cases where the number of sub-columns is a relatively small number.